# Is this generic autoboxing?

Tags: java, generics, autoboxing

Assigning values without using usual notation like "this.<Double>getAnything(int flag)"

```
private <T> T getAnything(int flag) {
    Object o = null;
    if (flag==0)
        o=new String("NewString");
    else if (flag==1)
        o=new Double(0D);
    return (T)o;
}


private void someMethod() {
    String s = getAnything(0);
    Double d = getAnything(1);
}
```

in the past it was enough only a return object on the method and a simple cast onthe receiveing type, so with the lacking of generic notation on the receiver object it is much more similar and fast to write, any other hint on this?

Comment: I fail to see what autoboxing has to do with this code. If you can comment on it, I can elaborate and hopefully clear up any confusion.

Comment: You should never use `new String("hello")` in Java. Just write `"hello"` - that's already a `String` object. No need to create another `String` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing autoboxing with type inference.

Type inference is when the compiler can tell what type it should use on a generic method on its own, from the variables used when calling the method.

For example if you have the following method:

```
public <T extends SomeClass> T process(T obj) {
    // call some methods of SomeClass on obj to process it here
    return obj;
}
```

and then call it like:

```
SomeChildClass a = new SomeChildClass(); // SomeChildClass extends SomeClass
a = process(a);
```

the inferred type will be SomeChildClass;

The type can be inferred from the parameters or from the return type, as is in your example. But it's not always obvious to the compiler what type it should use. If that happens you can force the type by using the method `this.<Double>getAnything(int flag)` that you described. This usually happens in situations like this:

```
public <T> List<T> getSomeList() {
    // implementation
}

public void processList(List<SomeClass> list) {
     // implementation
}
```

and calling

```
processList(getSomeList()); // compiler error: cannot convert List<Object> to List<SomeClass>
```

In cases like this you may need to force the type parameter.

All this being said, please take into consideration everything that polygenelubricants said as well, as he makes some very good points regarding your code and explains what autoboxing is (it's related to primitive wrapper classes like Integer for int, and Double for double).

Answer (score 5):

#### On typesafety

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but it should be pointed out that there's no typesafety what-so-ever in your code.

```
Double d = getAnything(0);
// compiles fine, but throws ClassCastException at run time
```

This defeats the purpose of using generics in the first place.

You introduced this unsafetiness when you wrote this statement:

```
return (T)o; // warning: Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to T
```

#### Related questions

- [What is `SuppressWarnings (“unchecked”)` in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129795/what-is-suppresswarnings-unchecked-in-java)
- [How do I address unchecked cast warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings)
- [Type safety: Unchecked cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262367/type-safety-unchecked-cast)

#### See also

- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 24: Eliminate unchecked warnings*

---

#### On Typesafe Heterogeneous Container

Perhaps you want something like what Josh Bloch calls the Typesafe Heterogeneous Container. Here's a quote from Neal Gafter's blog:

> Here is a simple but complete example of an API that uses type tokens in the
>   THC pattern, from Josh's 2006 JavaOne talk:
>
> ```
> public class Favorites {
>
>     private Map<Class<?>, Object> favorites =
>         new HashMap<Class<?>, Object>();
>
>     public <T> void setFavorite(Class<T> klass, T thing) {
>         favorites.put(klass, thing);
>     }
>     public <T> T getFavorite(Class<T> klass) {
>         return klass.cast(favorites.get(klass));
>     }
>
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         Favorites f = new Favorites();
>         f.setFavorite(String.class, "Java");
>         f.setFavorite(Integer.class, 0xcafebabe);
>
>         String s = f.getFavorite(String.class);
>         int i = f.getFavorite(Integer.class);
>     }
> }
> ```

With this pattern you get type-safety; `int i = f.getFavorite(String.class);` does *NOT* compile (which is a good thing!).

#### See also

- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 29: Consider typesafe heterogenous container*
- [Neal Gafter's Blog - Super Type Tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html)

---

#### On autoboxing

Autoboxing is the implicit conversion from say primitive `int` to reference type `Integer`; autounboxing is the opposite conversion. The question as stated has nothing to do with autoboxing.

#### See also

- [Java Language Guide/Autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)
- [JLS 5.1.7 Boxing Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.7) and [5.1.8 Unboxing Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.8)

#### Related questions

- [Java: What’s the difference between autoboxing and casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501653/java-whats-the-difference-between-autoboxing-and-casting)
- [Why does `int num = Integer.getInteger(“123”)` throw `NullPointerException`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123349/why-does-int-num-integer-getinteger123-throw-nullpointerexception)
- [What is the difference between an `int` and an `Integer` in Java/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-an-integer-in-java-c)
- [Why does autoboxing in Java allow me to have 3 possible values for a `boolean`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923249/why-does-autoboxing-in-java-allow-me-to-have-3-possible-values-for-a-boolean/)
- [Is it guaranteed that `new Integer(i) == i` in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831945/is-it-guaranteed-that-new-integeri-i-in-java) (YES!!!)
- [When comparing two Integers in Java does auto-unboxing occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/when-comparing-two-integers-in-java-does-auto-unboxing-occur)  (NO!!!)
- [Java noob: generics over objects only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015716/java-noob-generics-over-objects-only/) (yes, unfortunately)