# for loop structure

Tags: java

This program will calculate the average grade for 4 exams using a for loop by prompting 
the user for exam grades, one at a time, then calculate the average and display the result.

```
public class ExamsFor4 {

public static void main(String[] arguments) {


int inputNumber; // One of the exams input by the user.
int sum = 0;     // The sum of the exams.
int i;       // Number of exams.
Double Avg;      // The average of the exams.

TextIO.put("Please enter the first exam: ");        // get the first exam.
inputNumber = TextIO.getlnInt();    

for ( i = 1; i <= 4; i++ ) {  

    sum += inputNumber;                 // Add inputNumber to running sum.
    TextIO.put("Please enter the next exam: ");     // get the next exam.   
    inputNumber = TextIO.getlnInt();

        if (i == 4) {
            Avg = ((double)sum) / i;
            TextIO.putln();
            TextIO.putln("The total sum for all " + i +" exams is " + sum);
            TextIO.putf("The average for the exams entered is %1.2f.\n", Avg);
            break;

        }
} 

}   // end main ()
}  // end class ExamsFor4
```

My result:

```
Please enter the first exam: 100
Please enter the next exam: 99
Please enter the next exam: 98
Please enter the next exam: 97
Please enter the next exam: 96
The total sum for all 4 exams is 394
The average for the exams entered is 98.50.
```

This would be correct except for the last print out of: '`Please enter the next exam: 96`'
I tried putting the IF statement between the '`sum`' line and the `TextIO.put 'Enter next exam'`, but that isolates it.

Thanks, from a Network Dude trap in a Programmer's world.

Comment: this is the type of thing you're supposed to struggle through and either figure out on your own or fail.  I'm glad I didn't have stack overflow as a resource when I was in school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably put the if-statment outside the for-loop. That way you don't need the if-statement. Second the statement in the loop should be < 4 instead of <= 4.

```
public class ExamsFor4 {

public static void main(String[] arguments) {


int inputNumber; // One of the exams input by the user.
int sum = 0;     // The sum of the exams.
int i;       // Number of exams.
Double Avg;      // The average of the exams.

TextIO.put("Please enter the first exam: ");        // get the first exam.
inputNumber = TextIO.getlnInt();    

for ( i = 1; i < 4; i++ ) {  

    sum += inputNumber;                 // Add inputNumber to running sum.
    TextIO.put("Please enter the next exam: ");     // get the next exam.   
    inputNumber = TextIO.getlnInt();
} 

Avg = ((double)sum) / i;
TextIO.putln();
TextIO.putln("The total sum for all " + i +" exams is " + sum);
TextIO.putf("The average for the exams entered is %1.2f.\n", Avg);
break;

}   // end main ()
}
```

Comment: This is cleaner but the results are the same?

Comment: No I was wrong.  It now appears to stop correctly after 4 entries, but the last entry doesn't get added to the sum.  
Still fighting the one-off error.

Comment: I had to remove the lines asking for input before the loop.

     for (i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {  
     TextIO.put("Please enter an exam: "); // get the next exam.   
     inputNumber = TextIO.getlnInt();
     sum += inputNumber;    // Add inputNumber to running sum.  
     } 

Thanks to all for helping me work through this.

Comment: This code as is doesn't add the last `inputNumber` to the `sum`.

Answer (score 12):

You have what is called an *off-by-one error*, compounded by the fact that you're convoluting your loop logic unnecessarily.

With regards to the loop, I recommend two things:

- Don't loop `for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)`; it's atypical

  - Do `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)`; it's more typical
- Instead of checking for the last iteration to do something, refactor and take it outside of the loop

#### Related questions

- [What is exactly the off-by-one errors in the while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939869/what-is-exactly-the-off-by-one-errors-in-the-while-loop)

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Off-by-one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)

---

#### On `Double Avg`

In Java, variable names start with lowercase. Moreover, `Double` is a reference type, the box for the primitive `double`. Whenever possible, you should prefer `double` to `Double`

#### See also

- [Java Language Guide/Autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)
- [JLS 5.1.7 Boxing Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.7) and [5.1.8 Unboxing Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.8)
- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 49: Prefer primitives to boxed primitives*

#### Related questions

- [What is the difference between an `int` and an `Integer` in Java/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-an-integer-in-java-c)
- [Java: What’s the difference between autoboxing and casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501653/java-whats-the-difference-between-autoboxing-and-casting)
- [Why does `int num = Integer.getInteger(“123”)` throw `NullPointerException`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123349/why-does-int-num-integer-getinteger123-throw-nullpointerexception)
- [Why does autoboxing in Java allow me to have 3 possible values for a `boolean`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923249/why-does-autoboxing-in-java-allow-me-to-have-3-possible-values-for-a-boolean/)
- [Is it guaranteed that `new Integer(i) == i` in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831945/is-it-guaranteed-that-new-integeri-i-in-java) (YES!!!)
- [When comparing two Integers in Java does auto-unboxing occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/when-comparing-two-integers-in-java-does-auto-unboxing-occur)  (NO!!!)
- [Java noob: generics over objects only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015716/java-noob-generics-over-objects-only/) (yes, unfortunately)

---

#### Rewrite

Here's a way to rewrite the code that makes it more readable. I used `java.util.Scanner` since I don't think `TextIO` is standard, but the essence remains the same.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ExamsFor4 {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int NUM_EXAMS = 4;
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_EXAMS; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Please enter the %s exam: ",
                (i == 0) ? "first" : "next"
            );
            sum += sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.printf("Total is %d%n", sum);
        System.out.printf("Average is %1.2f%n", ((double) sum) / NUM_EXAMS);
    }
}
```

An example session is as follows:

```
Please enter the first exam: 4
Please enter the next exam: 5
Please enter the next exam: 7
Please enter the next exam: 9
Total is 25
Average is 6.25
```

Note that:

- Only necessary variables are declared

  - The loop index is local only to the loop
- There are no cluttering comments

  - Instead, focus on writing clear, concise, readable code
- If it makes sense to make something `final`, do so

  - Constants in Java is all uppercase

#### Related questions

- [Why does `(360 / 24) / 60 = 0` in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475652/why-does-360-24-60-0-in-java/)

  - Because it performs integer division.  This is why the cast to `(double)` prior to the division in above code is necessary, so that it performs floating point division.
- [How does the ternary operator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463155/how-does-the-ternary-operator-work)

  - This is the `?:` operator in above code, also known as the conditional operator.
  - See also: [JLS 15.25 Conditional Operator ?:](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25)

Answer (score 3):

Change your end condition to be strictly less than 4 and put the code that prints out the total and average outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just making few changes in your code makes it work. But you should follow cleaner approach as proposed in some of answers.

```
public class ExamsFor4 {

  public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    int inputNumber; // One of the exams input by the user.
    int sum = 0;     // The sum of the exams.
    int i;       // Number of exams.
    double Avg;      // The average of the exams.

    TextIO.put("Please enter the first exam: ");        // get the first exam.
    inputNumber = TextIO.getlnInt();    
    sum += inputNumber;

    for ( i = 1; i < 4; i++ ) {  

      TextIO.put("Please enter the next exam: ");     // get the next exam.   
      inputNumber = TextIO.getlnInt();
      sum += inputNumber;                 // Add inputNumber to running sum.

    } 

    Avg = ((double)sum) / i;
    TextIO.putln();
    TextIO.putln("The total sum for all " + i +" exams is " + sum);
    TextIO.putf("The average for the exams entered is %1.2f.\n", Avg);

  }   // end main ()
}  // end class ExamsFor4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ExamsFor4 {

public static void main(String[] arguments) {

    int sum = 0; // The sum of the exams.
    int i = 1; // Number of exams.
    double avg = 0; // The average of the exams.

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the first exam: ");
    sum += in.nextInt();
    i++;
    while(i<=4){
        System.out.print("Please enter the next exam: ");
        sum += in.nextInt();
        if(i==4)
            break;// this line is so that it wont increment an extra time.
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("The total sum for all " + i +" exams is " + sum);
    avg = ((double)sum/i);
    System.out.println("The average for the exams entered is" + avg);
} // end main ()
} // end class ExamsFor4
```